# Is it possible to bind src to image from local json file in Vue.js?

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a local JSON file which have an image in it

```
[{
  "image": "/img/slider-first.jpg"
}]
```

I'm requiring it in my component

```
const data = require('../assets/pets-data.json')
```

And do this

```
<ul v-for="d in data" :key="d.name">
        <img
          :src="'../assets'+d.image"
          alt="">
</ul>
```

That doesn't work, my image doesn't load.

In html it looks like this
[image]

Structure of my project
[image]

So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues. What's working for me in one project with a similar requirement - that is, I have a json file with dozens of objects, each of which has a "url" key and and image file name as its value:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "img": "pic01.png",
        "metadata": "blah de blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "img": "pic02.png",
        "metadata": "blah de blah"
    }, // etc.
```

... which lives in a 'data' folder which is a sibling of the 'src' directory. The directory containing the images lives in the 'static' directory (a sibling of the 'src' directory), and in my component:

```
import Gallery from '../../data/gallery.json';

export default {
    name: 'Gallery',
    data () {
        return {
            gallery: Gallery
            ...
```

... and the template:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="obj in gallery" v-bind:key="obj.id">
        <a href="#" v-bind:title="obj.metadata">
            <img :src="'/static/gallery/'+obj.img" v-bind:alt="obj.metadata" v-bind:title="obj.metadata" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Dunno if this is the cleverest approach - maybe there's a webpack config that would simplify this, or enable more options as to where the images are kept ... but it works for me, hopefully this will work for you too. Good luck!